# Garbage in file after truncate(0) in Python

Tags: python

Assume there is a file `test.txt` containing a string `'test'`.

Now, consider the following Python code:

```
f = open('test', 'r+')
f.read()
f.truncate(0)
f.write('passed')
f.flush();
```

Now I expect `test.txt` to contain `'passed'` now, however there are additionally some strange symbols!

Update: flush after truncate does not help.

Comment: As far as I can tell, running `truncate(0)` simply sets the file size to 0 bytes and moves the file pointer back to the start of the buffer. When you write to the stream before the flush, the state of the buffer is undefined. When you flush, garbage data may appear from that buffer. The general rule I would apply is that you should flush whenever you try to *remove* anything, or when you need to ensure the file is in a particular state before continuing.

Comment: what about closing the file ?

Comment: @Polynomial flush doesn't work also, I was mistaken...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [truncate](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=flush#io.IOBase.truncate) doesn't change the stream position.

When you `read()` the file, you move the position to the end. So successive `write`s will write to file from that position. <del>However, when you call `flush()`, it seems not only it tries to write the buffer to the file, but also does some error checking and fixes the current file position. When `Flush()` is called after the `truncate(0)`, writes nothing (buffer is empty), then checks the file size and places the position at the first applicable place (which is `0`).</del>

**UPDATE**

Python's file function are NOT just wrappers around the C standard library equivalents, but knowing the C functions helps knowing what is happening more precisely.

From the [ftruncate man page](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ftruncate+3):

> The value of the seek pointer is  not  modified by a call to ftruncate().

From the [fflush man page](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fflush+3):

> If stream points to an input stream or an update stream into which  the  most  recent operation was input, that stream is flushed if it is seekable and is not already at end-of-file. Flushing  an  input  stream  discards any buffered input and adjusts the file pointer such that the next input  operation accesses  the  byte  after  the  last one read.

This means if you put `flush` before `truncate` it has no effect. I checked and it was so.

But for putting `flush` after `truncate`:

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream  in which  the  most  recent  operation  was not input, fflush() causes any unwritten data for that stream to be  written  to the file, and the st_ctime and st_mtime fields of the underlying file are marked for update.

The man page doesn't mention the seek pointer when explaining output streams with last operation not being input. (Here our last operation is `truncate`)

**UPDATE 2**

I found something in python source code: `Python-3.2.2\Modules\_io\fileio.c:837`

```
#ifdef HAVE_FTRUNCATE
static PyObject *
fileio_truncate(fileio *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *posobj = NULL; /* the new size wanted by the user */
#ifndef MS_WINDOWS
    Py_off_t pos;
#endif

...

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    /* MS _chsize doesn't work if newsize doesn't fit in 32 bits,
       so don't even try using it. */
    {
        PyObject *oldposobj, *tempposobj;
        HANDLE hFile;

////// THIS LINE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /* we save the file pointer position */
        oldposobj = portable_lseek(fd, NULL, 1);
        if (oldposobj == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(posobj);
            return NULL;
        }

        /* we then move to the truncation position */
        ...

        /* Truncate.  Note that this may grow the file! */
        ...

////// AND THIS LINE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /* we restore the file pointer position in any case */
        tempposobj = portable_lseek(fd, oldposobj, 0);
        Py_DECREF(oldposobj);
        if (tempposobj == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(posobj);
            return NULL;
        }
        Py_DECREF(tempposobj);
    }
#else

...

#endif /* HAVE_FTRUNCATE */
```

Look at the two lines I indicated (`///// This Line /////`). If your platform is Windows, then it's saving the position and returning it back after the truncate.

To my surprise, most of the `flush` functions inside the Python 3.2.2 functions either did nothing or did not call `fflush` C function at all. The 3.2.2 truncate part was also very undocumented. However, I did find something interesting in Python 2.7.2 sources. First, I found this in `Python-2.7.2\Objects\fileobject.c:812` in `truncate` implementation:

```
 /* Get current file position.  If the file happens to be open for
 * update and the last operation was an input operation, C doesn't
 * define what the later fflush() will do, but we promise truncate()
 * won't change the current position (and fflush() *does* change it
 * then at least on Windows).  The easiest thing is to capture
 * current pos now and seek back to it at the end.
 */
```

So to summarize all, I think this is a fully platform dependent thing. I checked on default Python 3.2.2 for Windows x64 and got the same results as you. Don't know what happens on *nixes.

Comment: See my update, but I think you are on the right track. I probably should seek to zero additionally. -- Yes seeking to 0 just after truncating helps! So what is the real purpose of truncate then?!

Comment: My OS is Linux, so I suspect the same behavior on other POSIX compatible systems.

Answer (score 14):

Yeah, that's true that `truncate()` doesn't move the position, but said that, is simple as death:

```
f.read()
f.seek(0)
f.truncate(0)
f.close()
```

this is perfectly working ;)

Comment: Great, thanks for providing the only actual solution to this problem:)
OP - I'd suggest to accept this answer.

Comment: This is the only real solution - seek(0) solved it perfectly. Thank dear

Answer (score 3):

Truncate doesn't change the file position.

Note also that even if the file is opened in read+write you cannot just switch between the two types of operation (a seek operation is required to be able to switch from read to write or vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is in the same boat as mine, here is my problem with solution:

- I have a program that is always ON i.e. it doesn't stop, keeps on polling the data and writes to a log file
- The problem is, i want to split the main file as soon as it reaches the 10 MB mark, therefore, i wrote the below program.
- I found the solution as well to the problem, where truncate was writing null values to the file causing further problem.

Below is an illustration on how i solved this issue.

```
f1 = open('client.log','w')
nowTime = datetime.datetime.now().time() 
f1.write(os.urandom(1024*1024*15)) #Adding random values worth 15 MB
if (int(os.path.getsize('client.log') / 1048576) > 10): #checking if file size is 10 MB and above
    print 'File size limit Exceeded, needs trimming'
    dst = 'client_'+ str(randint(0, 999999)) + '.log'       
    copyfile('client.log', dst) #Copying file to another one
    print 'Copied content to ' + str(dst)
    print 'Erasing current file'
    f1.truncate(0) #Truncating data, this works fine but puts the counter at the last 
    f1.seek(0)  #very important to use after truncate so that new data begins from 0 
    print 'File truncated successfully'
    f1.write('This is fresh content') #Dummy content
f1.close()  
print 'All Job Processed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect the following is the code you meant to write:

```
open('test.txt').read()
open('test.txt', 'w').write('passed')
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends.  If you want to keep the file open and access it without closing it then flush will force writing to the file.  If you're closing the file right after flush then no you don't need it because close will flush for you.  That's my understanding from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html?highlight=flush#io.IOBase.flush)

Comment: I want to clear the file... and no, I do not want to reopen it.