# I want to clear a text file and add two textlines to it in python

Tags: python, text, text-files

First of all this is my Code:

```
c = open('Tasks//Task_Counter.txt', 'r+')
okay = c.read().splitlines()

which_task = int(okay[0])
this_task = which_task + 1 

which_port = int(okay[1])
this_port = which_port + 1

c.truncate(0)

c.write(str(this_task))
c.write("\n")
c.write(str(this_port))
```

In the Task_Counter.txt file are basically just these two lines written down:

```
10
9259
```

Now I wanna replace them with:

```
11
9260
```

But somehow this is the result:

```
        11
9260
```

As you can see there is just free Space and I dont know why there is this free Space.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

`.truncate()` doesn't change the file cursor position. So you have to use `.seek(0)` to write at the begin.
And don't forget to close your file. The best way is to use the context manager (`with`).

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r+') as c:
    okay = c.read().splitlines()

    which_task = int(okay[0])
    this_task = which_task + 1

    which_port = int(okay[1])
    this_port = which_port + 1

    c.truncate(0)
    c.seek(0)
    
    c.write(str(this_task))
    c.write("\n")
    c.write(str(this_port))
```

Comment: This is right: `c.seek(0)` is the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is file is not empty after truncate(0) is explained by [Garbage in file after truncate(0) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945370/garbage-in-file-after-truncate0-in-python/46384466).

So a better way is the following:

```
def update(filenm):
    # Get values  this_task and this_port
    with open(filenm, 'r') as f:    # open for read
        this_task = int(next(f))
        this_port = int(next(f))
        
    # Store incremented values
    with open(filenm, 'w') as f:    # open for write (places stream at beginning of file)
        f.write(f'{this_task + 1}\n')
        f.write(f'{this_port + 1}\n')

# Test (attempt 100 times)
for _ in range(100):
    update('Task_Counter.txt.txt')
```

Data in file after 100 iterations

```
111
2160
```