# Clear or empty the log file without blank spaces in python

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to empty a log file created in logging.ini as shown below, with this approach it clears the contents but the empty spaces of the contents still exist and then the new contents will be appended to it.

```
[handler_filehandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=json
args=("../logs/test_log.log",'w')
```

```
fn_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                       '..',
                       'logs',
                       'test_log.log')
fn_path = os.path.abspath(fn_path)

with open(fn_path, 'w'):
   pass
```

Have attached a image below of log when I open it in notepad

it shows empty contents on the second run of my application at first run there are no empty line, i clear the log once the first run is done , on the second run the logs are added after empty line

How can I clear all the contents without any empty spaces left in log file
[image]

Comment: Please share an example. What do you mean by "the empty spaces of the contents still exist"? The flags - `w`/`a` are handled by the operating system, not Python.

Comment: @DanielTrugman Have edited my post please check

Comment: How do you open the file? Are you sure it's not a different view? What OS are you running on?

Comment: Opening it with notepad in windows OS

Comment: Does your solution append empty lines? Did you try `with open(..., "w") as f: f.write("")`? What happens then?

Comment: Looks like python is not directly calling the OS's implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945370/garbage-in-file-after-truncate0-in-python/46384466

Comment: No this happens on the second run of my application at first run there are no empty line, i clear the log once the first run is done , on the second run the logs are added after empty line

Comment: Dear @she Please do not add informations as comments. Edit your own question please.

Comment: What library are you using that takes that INI file? And where in your code do you actually use it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer logging and  logging.config

Comment: Okay, so can you show where you are importing the logging library and loading the file in comparison to where you're trying to clear the file? Also, I'd expect `args=("../logs/test_log.log",'w')` to be clearing the file itself, not appending to previous logs